# How can I configure TortoiseSVN to work with an online BitBucket repo?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I am having a bit of an annoying issue here.

We have a private BitBucket central repo and each of us have cloned it on our desktop but we are using [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) which is not my favourite.

So my question is how can I configure TortoiseSvn t work with it?

I tried the following:

1. Created a folder on my desktop
2. Right clicked on it -> SVN Checkout
3. Pasted the https link to my BitBucket repo and pressed OK
4. And get the following error

> Checkout from https://xxxxxx@bitbucket.org/xxxxx/xxxxx.git, revision
>   HEAD, Fully recursive, Externals included Unable to connect to a
>   repository at URL 'https://xxxxxx@bitbucket.org/xxxxx/xxxxx.git'
>   Repository moved temporarily to
>   'https://bitbucket.org/account/signin/%3Fnext=/xxxxx/xxxxx.git';
>   please relocate Completed!

The reason I think this is happening is because it is not authenticated and I need to somehow force Tortoise to log in but I am not sure how.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Can't use TortoiseSVN. Must use TortoiseGIT.

Comment: @Dialecticus could you please add your comment as an answer? Short and sweet!!! Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Bitbucket.org hosts Git and Mercurial repositories, so you need a proper client, like [TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/) for Git, or [TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/) for Mercurial.

Comment: “Bitbucket.org hosts git repositories”: not exactly… it hosts Git and Mercurial repositories, and I even believe Mercurial is the most encountered type of repository on BitBucket.